# rsync - report only uploaded files

Tags: rsync

I have a problem with rsync: either it shows me all files in the directories I am rsyncing (if using the flag `-v`) or nothing at all (when not using `-v`).

I would like to have rsync quiet *except* for the files which actually had to be uploaded to the far end. Is there a flag to activate this kind of reporting? I can not find this in the documentation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, check out the `-i` flag. It gives a report of every operation in a cryptic format. See the man page for the exact definition of the format.

In order to get the list of files which are sent to the remote host, you could use the following:

```
rsync <options> -i <src> <dst> | grep '^<' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: This is reporting again all files, not the changed ones.

Comment: @gonvaled No, only the files which are sent to the remote host are output (as `<fcstpoguax filename`, where the different flags show why they need to be updated). If it reports all files, something may be wrong with your test or your environment.

Comment: I think you are right. I have taken a look at the manpage and it is described as you say. But my system is reporting all files. Maybe something wrong with the far-end ...

Comment: Mmmm. getting closer: the reporting string is (for all files) `<f..T......`. According to the manpage, this is related to timestamps.

Comment: Do you call rsync with `--times`?

Comment: This did it: `rsync <options> --times -i <src> <dst>`. And I learnt something more about rsync: In order for the full optimizations to work, you need `--times`.

Comment: Most of the time, I call rsync with the `-a` option. This also includes `--times`.

Comment: @gonvaled: Assuming you think it's okay to skip checking the actual contents of files that have the same timestamp and size on both ends. I'm not so sure that's a good idea.

Comment: @David: thanks for pointing out the risk. But I consider it a minor risk. I mean, the same size *and* the same timestamp! I am not backing up important data, it is just for a software deploy. I can not think of a situation where I will run into problems with this.

Comment: using `grep -E '^[^.]|^$'` would also let statistic (or warnings, errors,...) lines through, only removing the really boring lines starting with a dot...

Comment: With `rsync` (3.1.3  protocol version 31), here's the sed filter I use: `sed -nr 's/^[><].+?\s+(.+)$/\1/ p'`

Answer (score 12):

rsync with a single `-v|--verbose` actually prints only transferred files (as well as a header/footer). If you are getting the complete list every time then it probably means that the default rsync src/dest comparison algorithm, which is based on modification time + size, is not suitable for your case. You may add the `-c` (`--checksum`) flag which makes rsync compare files by checksumming. Note that this obviously incurs some I/O overhead.

Slightly related is the fact that if you use `--info=flist` instead of `-v` then you get a more trimmed output of the files (you basically skip the header and footer of the typical `-v` output).

Comment: `--info=flist` is only available in rsync >= 3.1, which is not available everywhere. For example macOS is delivered with an ancient version 2.6.9 because Rsync v3 is unter GPL 3.

Comment: While that Apple GPL rumour is super-juicy, also remember that Enterprise Linux has a massive support range (14 years) where versions are locked (and branched) to preserve certification and guarantee compatibility (api+abi) over the supported life of the release.  It's actually the only feasible way of doing that, and the side effect is that version numbers appear old and new features don't hit the Enterprise for what may seem like a Long time.

Comment: I believe the `--info=flist` flag may have changed. `--info=name` gives me the output expected  on`rsync 3.1.3`

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Use the `-i` option

For these iconized (or: cryptic) change flags. You output will look like this:

```
*deleting   DSC00012 (copy).JPG
.d..tp..... ./
.f...p..... DSC00011.JPG
>f+++++++++ DSC00012 (copy2).JPG
>f.stp..... DSC00012.JPG
.f...p..... DSC00014.JPG

Number of files: 5 (reg: 4, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
... more statistic stuff
sent 636.01K bytes  received 4.63K bytes  1.28M bytes/sec
total size is 2.84M  speedup is 4.44
```

## 2. grep every line starting with a dot.

Let all other lines (also blank ones, for legibility) pass:

```
rsync -arz -i --stats -h ... /mnt/FooDrive/ /mnt/backup  | grep -E '^[^.]|^$'
```

**And here we are :-) — Just what the doctor ordered:**

```
*deleting   DSC00012 (copy2).JPG
>f.stp..... DSC00011.JPG
>f+++++++++ DSC00012 (copy).JPG

Number of files: 5 (reg: 4, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
...
```

*Avoiding dots* rather than *hunting for* `>` has the benefit to also let statistics, but also potential errors, warnings etc pass through...

Having stats at the end is a personal preference. Don't use `-h --stats` if you don't like these. I assume your key interest is in not seeing hundred or thousands of unchanged files scroll by...

Comment: what does `.d...p......` mean in front of each file?

Answer (score 2):

one thing that comes to my mind is using more verbose log format and awk'ing out what you want to get.

eg:

```
rsync -a --out-format="%b  %i %f" /etc/ /tmp/qq/ |awk '{if ($1>0) {print $3}}'
```

this is not very robust, it'll not handle well file-names with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a flag to do this but there might be now.  Here was the way I did it:

```
rsync -vv [other options] | grep -v 'uptodate'
```

Comment: My rsync (version 3.0.7) does not add `uptodate` to the reporting, so not possible to filter that out.

Comment: I want to correct, or at least clarify, what Mike posted above and what @jeckyll2hide pointed out. I think the issue is not that rsync -v no longer emits the string "uptodate" but rather that you need to use rsync -vv. Note the two vs. I just verified this works on Ubuntu 14.04 with rsync version 3.1.0. Mike, can you update your post to reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -av --delete-before --force --progress /path/to/src/dir/ -e ssh user@host:/path/to/target/dir | grep -v '.*\/$'
```

This works for me ("rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31" on src machine and "rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31" on target machine to be exact). It simply omits any lines with trailing slash, which are the main portion of unchanged stuff just scrolling by needlessly. grep -v inverts the search pattern, so only non-matching lines are output. Have been searching for this for ages, finally got around to figuring it out. Hope it is useful to you!

Correction: There needs to be a backslash before the slash in the grep expression for it to work the way it should, added it