# How to output a list of changed files from rsync?

Tags: bash, scripting, rsync

I am using rsync in a bash script to keep files in sync between a few servers and a NAS. One issue I have run into is trying to generate a list of the files that have changed from the during the rsync.

The idea is that when I run rsync, I can output the files that have changed into a text file - more hoping for an array in memory - then before the script exists I can run a chown on **only** the changed files.

Has anyone found a way to perform such a task?

```
# specify the source directory
source_directory=/Users/jason/Desktop/source

# specify the destination directory
# DO NOT ADD THE SAME DIRECTORY NAME AS RSYNC WILL CREATE IT FOR YOU
destination_directory=/Users/jason/Desktop/destination

# run the rsync command
rsync -avz $source_directory $destination_directory

# grab the changed items and save to an array or temp file?

# loop through and chown each changed file
for changed_item in "${changed_items[@]}"
do
        # chown the file owner and notify the user
        chown -R user:usergroup; echo '!! changed the user and group for:' $changed_item
done
```

Comment: → see [my anwer here](http://serverfault.com/a/834981/88431). Also `-i` for itemize, but with a few more twists...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use rsync's `--itemize-changes` (`-i`) option to generate a parsable output that looks like this:

```
~ $ rsync src/ dest/ -ai
.d..t.... ./
>f+++++++ newfile
>f..t.... oldfile

~ $ echo 'new stuff' > src/newfile

~ $ !rsync
rsync src/ dest/ -ai
>f.st.... newfile
```

The `>` character in the first position indicates a file was updated, the remaining characters indicate why, for example here `s` and `t` indicate that the file size and timestamp changed.

A quick and dirty way to get the file list might be:

`rsync -ai src/ dest/ | egrep '^>'`

Obviously more advanced parsing could produce cleaner output :-)

I came across this great link while trying to find out when `--itemize-changes` was introduced, very useful:

[http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20160904174444/http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html) (archived link)

Comment: For a cleaner output as mentioned, `rsync -zaic src/ dest/ | grep '^?c' | cut -d' ' -f2 --dry-run` would only list the modified files (**different checksum**) , definitely a keeper, thx :)
FYI putting `--dry-run` after the command instead of using the `n` option is for me a best practice

Comment: Essentially the same as `rsync -zavc src/ dest/ --dry-run` without verbose

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know the `!` syntax for using previous parameters... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20):

Use the `-n` flag, combined with the `-c` checksum flag and the `-i` flag:

```
# rsync -naic test/ test-clone/
>fcst...... a.txt
>fcst...... abcde.txt
>fcst...... b.txt
```

In this example, three files have changed, based on the contents (as determined by the checksum) of the file itself. However, no file syncing is done because of the `-n` flag

**Bonus**

If you want to run chown on the changed files, parse them out with `sed` or similar and process with xargs, for example:

```
rsync -naic test/ test-clone/ | sed 's/............//' | xargs -I+ sudo chown root "test-clone/+"
```

Comment: `sed` -> `cut -d ' ' -f2,-`

Comment: `-n --dry-run`, `-c --checksum`, `-i --itemize-changes`

Comment: I'm not following. All 3 of those files in the example are marked '>fcst' which I understand means 'being received from the remote', checksum differs, size differs, time differs. What in the output indicates that "only one file has changed"??

Comment: @bobpaul: I was puzzling over the same question when I read your comment (great minds...?  :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification, @Seamus

Answer (score 9):

This question is a little bit old, but I think it worth to be added:

`-i` is a shortcut of `--out-format='%i %n%L'`

`%i` represents a cryptic, 11 character output whose format is the string `YXcstpoguax`; ref `man rsync`, `-itemize-changes`.
And `%n` means the filename, (section `log format` of `man rsyncd.conf`); `%L` comes into play when there are symlinks to update.

P.S. rsync version 3.1.0

Comment: Actually [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/401219/455397) mentioned that option

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing a few other answers (especially @Cychih's), you can get the list of changed files like so:

```
rsync --out-format='%n' src/ dest/
```

Which will print *only* the changed files, eg;

```
rsync --out-format='%n' src/ dest/
a.txt
bcde.txt
b.txt
```

You can save that to a list this way:

```
changed_items=($(rsync --out-format='%n' src/ dest/))
for item in "${items[@]}"; do
   echo $item
   echo $item
done
```

You can pipe them to another command like so:

```
rsync --out-format='%n' src/ dest/ | xargs open
```

Note that it's very common to include `-acz` (archive, checksum, and compress) flags as well.

Comment: `rsync -r --out-format='%n' src/ dest/` seemed to print every file for me.

Comment: Same for me, this just prints every file, just the same as `-v`, but excluding the summary at the end